# Update multiple records using mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am writing a service class (mongo_service.js) in order to keep my CRUD operations seperate for a project.

Below is the code to update multiple items.

```
updateMultipleCollection(Model, searchObject, collectionNewToUpdate) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Model.update( searchObject, collectionNewToUpdate, {new:true, multi:true}, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve (data);
            console.info("Multiple updates successful");
        });
    });
};
```

This works fine but the promise won't return the updated objects and I was wondering whether there was any other way to overcome this??

NOTE: In mongoose documentation they have mentioned that .update() will not return the updated objects whereas .findOneAndUpdate() does.

Comment: I think with `update` there is no way to do that because.  I think it returns a document that contains the status of the operation not the document from the database.

Comment: Many Thnaks for your help jack blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do a `.find()` and that will return an array.

Then do a `forEach` over the array and do `.save` on each doc. The new doc should be in the callback of `.save`

Comment: Many Thnaks for your help